# Vertical pagination, make li elements same width?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The li elements are not the same size, also, the first and last li elements have rounded borders, how do I make all li elements have the same width and no rounded borders?
**HTML:**

```
<div style="margin-left:5px;float:left;width:25px;">
    <ul id="paginacao" class="pagination">
        <li><a>A</a></li>
        <li><a>B</a></li>
        <li><a>C</a></li>
        <li><a>D</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#paginacao li{
    width:40px;
    max-width:40px;
}
```

**Bootply:**
http://www.bootply.com/KN9RHyoEYc#

Comment: You look at the actual css used to create the pagination via the un-minified source and you use the same or greater specificity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target `a` instead of the li element.

```
#paginacao li a {
    width:40px;
    max-width:40px;
    text-align: center;
}
```